# Python printing without commas

Tags: python

How can I print lists without brackets and commas?

I have a list of permutations like this:

```
   [1, 2, 3]
   [1, 3, 2] etc..
```

I want to print them like this: `1 2 3`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
blah = [ [1,2,3], [1,3,2] ]

for bla in blah:
    print ' '.join(map(str, bla))
```

It's worth noting that `map` is a bit old-fashioned and is better written as either a generator or list-comp depending on requirements. This also has the advantage that it'll be portable across Python 2.x & 3.x as it'll generate a list on 2.x, while remain lazy on 3.x

So, the above would be written (using a generator expression) as:

```
for bla in blah:
    print ' '.join(str(n) for n in bla)
```

Or using string formatting:

```
for bla in blah:
    print '{} {} {}'.format(*bla)
```

Comment: The last requires the list to have three elements though. You might use somethihng like `" ".join(['{}'] * len(bla))` though but that's hardly pretty, or `("{} "*len(bla))[:-1].format`

Comment: The use of `map()` is being discouraged in favor of list comprehensions and generator expressions.

Answer (score 4):

If the list is

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Printing the list without bracket and commas:

```
print " ".join(map(str,l))

#1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Print(*Number_list, sep="") # empty quote
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Example you have a list called names.

```
names = ["Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann"]
for name in range(len(names)):
    print names[name],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: blah = [ [1,2,3], [1,3,2] ]

In [2]: for x in blah:
   ...:     print x[0],x[1],x[2]
   ...:     
1 2 3
1 3 2

In [3]:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
i = 1
x = []
while (i <= n):
    x.append(i)
    i = i+1
print(*x, sep='')
```

assuming n is a number input by a user, you can run through a loop and add the values i to n to a list x. at the end, you can print the array (*x) using nothing ('') to separate the values. this keeps your values in their original format, in this case a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

**Code:**

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]]

for item in list:
    print("{}".format(item, end="\n")
```

**Result:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
completedWord=['s','o','m','e',' ','w','o','r','d','s']
print(*completedWords,sep=' ')
```

output = `s o m e w o r d s`
note there are two spaces in ***sep='  '***

Answer (score -1):

```
temp = [[2,3,5],[2,5,3]]
for each_temp in temp:
    if isinstance(each_temp,list):
        for nested_temp in each_temp:
            print nested_temp
```